# Расширение для Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Пишу расширение для `Google Chrome`
Нужно, чтобы при открытии страницы в вк вставлялась надпись `<div>Содержимое.</div>`.

Но что-то не получается.

Вот манифест

```
    {
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "48.png"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "exclude_globs": [  ],
      "exclude_matches": [  ],
      "include_globs": [ "*" ],
      "js": [ "script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
   "converted_from_user_script": true,
   "icons": {
      "128": "128.png",
      "48": "48.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Script",
   "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

А вот script.js

```
function start(){
document.getElementById('profile_short').innerHTML = '<div>Содержимое.</div>';
}
start();
```

Comment: > Нужно что бы при открытии страницы в вк

А функция `start()` выполняется при запуске расширения. Чувствуете разницу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Манифест:

```
"content_scripts": [
"matches": ["http://vk.com/*","http://www.vk.com/*"]
"js": [ "script.js" ],
"run_at": "document_end"
],
permission: ["activeTab"]
```

в script.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

      /*код исполняется при полной готовности страницы*/

      var a = document.getElementById('profile_short');/*на всякий случай, если разработчики поменяли страницу*/

      if (a != null) a.innerHTML = '<div>Содержимое.</div>';/*если элемент найдет, то вносим изменения*/
})
```

желательно прописывать в `matches` на какой именно странице вк будет исполнятся код, либо проверять `window.location` в `script.js`

Comment: это уже другой совсем вопрос

Comment: var a = document.getElementById('profile_short');
if (a != null) {
var b = document.createElement('div');
b.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Содержимое'));
a.appendChild(b);
}

@slavutich, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: проверял, все работает, мануалы вам в помощь, удачи

Comment: Спасибо, но возникла проблема. Я кликаю по профилю пользователя  через друзей. То не появляется, но когда обновляю то появляется. Что делать?

Comment: потерял всю суть проблемы, как это "кликаю по профилю пользователя через друзей"?

Answer (score 0):

У меня была идентичная проблема, только я писал расширение для сайта хбох.ком
Настоятельно Вам рекомендую установить расширение TamperMonkey для хрома и писать юзерскрипты прямо в нём. Поверьте мне, это намного легче, чем писать расширения.

Comment: А если я хочу, чтобы моим скриптом пользовались и другие пользователи сети, что тогда делать? 
Разве не проще все-таки написать расширения для браузеров? Браузеров то всего 3, более-менее популярных. А "Обезьяна" далеко не у всех стоит.